# Require payload format to send the notifications with action buttons like accept/reject using azure notification hub

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I want to send the notifications with actions like accept/reject using azure notification hub and I am using Google FCM V1, so require payload which supports sending the actions

Tried this for FCM Legacy but didn't worked, however require payload for FCM v1 with actions
"{ "notification": { "title" : "PushDemo", "body" : "this is test message"}, "data" : { "action" : "action" } }");